# json web token - expiration time not clear

Tags: node.js, jwt, express-jwt

I'm using the jsonwebtoken package in node js. I'm generating a token like so:

```
var token = jwt.sign({ email: email }, secret, { expiresIn: 144000 });
```

The token is generated, but when I look at Chrome's cookies console, the value of "Expires / Max-Age" column is "Session", and not 24 hours from now as I would expect. I also tried setting expiresIn to '1d', but the result was the same.

Thanks.

Comment: That's a server token, nothing about browser cookies

Comment: But how does the server token work?

Comment: You are telling the server to respect that token for that amount of time.

Comment: OK, but where does the server keep the expiration date? And if it's a server token, what's the role of the token cookie I see in my console? Please explain the mechanism. Thanks.

Comment: It's possible that you are saving a token received from the server as a cookie. I think you are doing this b/c you mention looking in Chrome's "cookie console" (not in local storage). If you do that there are two expirations: the expiration that was specified when you set the cookie (in this case the cookie expires at the end of the users's session), and the expiration date contained/encoded in the JWT.

Comment: To see the expiration date in the JWT you need to decode the token (Chrome won't do that for you). Go to [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) and paste your token there to decode it.

Comment: Finally, I would advise that storing the token in a "session cookie" is not very useful, b/c the cookie will get deleted when they close their browser.

Comment: Check this article to understand how token-based authentication works: https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-ins-and-outs-of-token-based-authentication

Comment: @SunilD. I suggested to use cookies, rather than session cookies, as a place where to store the token on the client, as proposed, e.g., in https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the server computes the `token`, it must send it to the client. It is then the responsibility of the client to send the token as argument of the `Authorization` HTTP header for each subsequent HTTP request. In other words, the client is responsible for communicating the application state to the Web server for each single HTTP request.

How the client is going to store such information is out of the Web server's concerns, which only cares about the state of its own resources. Two common strategies are local storage and, again, cookies.

Since the token is self-contained, the server does not need to store the client state. That is, no server-side session is required, thus making the corresponding session cookie settings unrelated to the behavior of the token. As a matter of fact, the server only needs to decode the token as provided in the HTTP `Authorization` header in the request, and check the `exp` date. If the reported timestamp is greater than the current one, the token has expired and the server should refuse to further process the request.

Observe that these two aspects (i.e., the need for the client to take care of the application state and the consequent absence of such data in the server) allow implementing a client/server interaction in accordance with the REST stateless constraint.